# Replace Ninject with .NET Core built-in DI with typed parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have an old .NET application that uses Ninject to resolve an instance of an ICommandHandler as shown below. I also uses the Db context to call SaveChanges(). I'm now trying to convert this code so that I can use it in a new .NET Core application with its built-in Dependency Injection.

```
    public class CommandInvoker : ICommandInvoker
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;
        private readonly IArhomaContext _context;

        public CommandInvoker(IKernel kernel, IArhomaContext context)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Execute<T>(T command)
        {
            var handler = _kernel.TryGet<ICommandHandler<T>>();
            handler.Handle(command);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking that I have to add the following to the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler, CommandHandler>();
```

But ICommandHandler has a typed parameter. How is that done or registered?

Secondly, I need to resolve it to create a handler that executes the command. How does one resolve this in .NET Core?

P.S. I do not want to continue using Ninject in my .NET Core app.

Comment: ```services.AddScoped(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CommandHandler<>));```

Comment: Thanks Luke but how do I resolve it? In Ninject there is the kernel.TryGet<>, but how is this done in Core?

Comment: You are probably using the batch-registration feature of Ninject to register all your command handlers with one call. This is something that the Microsoft container doesn't have. This is something you have to build yourself or you need to use something 3rd party tool that can do this on top of the .NET Core container. Please note that there are many features missing from .NET Core that might be important to your application. Switching to this very simplistic DI implementation might not always yield the best results.

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer LukeHutton gave, to register use:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CommandHandler<>));
```

To resolve:

```
// You should only Build the provider once in your code, to do so:
var provider = services.BuilderServiceProvider(); //to protect against runtime injection, which is an anti-pattern

// to Get an Actual ICommandHandler
var commandHandler = services.GetService<ICommandHandler<MyT>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue, and I created some event handling structure to solve this issues on Asp.NET Core 2.0.
I created a event registrator that mapps the event handlers :

```
public class EventRegistrator : IEventRegistrator
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IList<Type>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, IList<Type>>();

    public IEventRegistrator Add<Event, Handler>()
        where Event : IEvent
        where Handler : IEventHandler<Event>
    {
        var eventType = typeof(Event);
        var handlerType = typeof(Handler);

        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
            dictionary[eventType] = new List<Type>();
        }

        dictionary[eventType].Add(handlerType);

        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetHandlers<Event>()
        where Event : IEvent
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(Event), out IList<Type> handlers))
        {
            return handlers;
        }

        return new List<Type>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetHandlers()
    {
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            foreach (var handler in item.Value)
            {
                yield return handler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following coded would be added to the startup :

```
    var registrator = new EventRegistrator()
        .Add<TrainerCreatedEvent, ProcessionalWelcomeMessageHandler>()
        .Add<TrainerCreatedEvent, ProfessionalCreatedCertificationStartHandler>();

services.AddSingleton<IEventRegistrator>(context =>
{
    return registrator; // All Event Handlers should be handled here
});

foreach (var handler in registrator.GetHandlers())
{
    services.AddTransient(handler);
}
```

Then the mediator ( the objects that dispatch or raise the event ) :

```
public class SimpleMediator : IMediator
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    private readonly IEventRegistrator registrator;

    public SimpleMediator(IEventRegistrator registrator, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.registrator = registrator;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public async Task Dispatch<T>(T target)
        where T : IEvent
    {
        var handlers = registrator.GetHandlers<T>();
        if (handlers == null) return;

        foreach (Type item in handlers)
        {
            var instance = (IEventHandler<T>)provider.GetService(item);
            if (instance == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"No type {item.ToString()} has been registred on the service collections. Add this type to the service collections.");

            await instance.HandleAsync(target);
        }
    }
}
```

The missing interfaces :

```
    public interface IMediator
{
    Task Dispatch<T>(T target)
        where T : IEvent;
}


public interface IEventRegistrator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register a handler to the event. Multiple handlers are supported
    /// </summary>
    IEventRegistrator Add<Event, Handler>()
        where Event : IEvent
        where Handler : IEventHandler<Event>;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all handlers to a event
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<Type> GetHandlers<Event>() where Event : IEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all handlers of all registered events.
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<Type> GetHandlers();
}
```